# Facebook C# SDK Maintaining Session State

Tags: facebook

I've downloaded Facebook C# SDK 4.1.0.

I'm using the Canvas IFrame MVC example and have successfully set up the project.

I have a question regarding the session state or in some ways lack of it.  I have a partial view that persists at the top of page the number of videos the user has uploaded.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult MyItemsTotal()
{
    FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp();
    ViewData["count"] = "0";
    int count = 0;

    if (app.Session != null)
        count = (from c in db.Items
                 where c.UserID == app.Session.UserId
                 select c).Count();

    if (count > 0)
        ViewData["count"] = count.ToString("#,#");

    return PartialView();
}
```

Sometimes however it works and shows the correct total each time, on other occasions it doesn't.  So I step through this routine and found that if (app.Session != null) is only true when the Request Method = "POST".  When it is "GET" it is false. Thus count is never called.

So there begs the question, why does Facebook C# SDK only persist the user session via POST and not GET as well?  Do I have to persist the user session myself and not rely on the Facebook App class to do it for me?

Regards,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

It is okay, this link here

http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=238671

gave me the answer.  I needed to use

Url.CanvasAction to make sure I was pointing to

apps.facebook.com/myapplication

:-P